# What is the correct way to stop a Godot dedicated server

Tags: godot, server

So I'm trying to understand how multiplayer works in Godot and the docs are very clear when one application is the host and the other applications join the host.

Now i want to have a dedicated server and there's 2 ways of doing that: just run the executable in headless mode or export it as a dedicated server for a smaller executable that can only be run in headless mode.

I then run the executable from cmd or powershell but I don't get how I would stop the server without throwing any errors (and saving data before actually terminating)

Just closing the console results in the following errors (for a split second) and doesn't trigger the close request notification:
[image]
The result is the same if I use the provided *.console.exe Godot produces. (Tried with 4.2 and 4.2.1)

This is independent from having actual network code and can be reproduced with an empty project.

So my question is: What is the correct way to stop a headless Godot application? (+is there a notification I can use to save game state?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### Close the server

In theory ideal way to close a server is for it to close itself, *if it is going to close at all*. And it should only be possible to trigger this locally. Since there is no Window, the standard way to do this is by reading from standard input.

*I'll try to do that for Godot...*

We will implement a custom `MainLoop`. Create a script like this:

```
class_name CustomMainLoop
extends SceneTree
```

And configure it in project settings under `application/run/main_loop_type`, you write the class name (`CustomMainLoop` inb this case), for example:

[image: MainLoopType set to CustomMainLoop]

And yes, this will be the `SceneTree` (not the `root` of the `SceneTree`, but the `SceneTree` itself).

Next we will override the `_initialize` method, and we will detect if we are running in headless mode:

```
func _initialize() -> void:
    if DisplayServer.get_name() != "headless":
        return
```

And we will read standard input with `OS.read_string_from_stdin()`. However, we need to run this in another thread because otherwise we are blocking the actual game.

Thus, let us do this:

```
class_name CustomMainLoop
extends SceneTree


var _input_thread:Thread


func _initialize() -> void:
    if DisplayServer.get_name() != "headless":
        return

    _input_thread = Thread.new()
    _input_thread.start(_listen_to_standard_input)


func _listen_to_standard_input() -> void:
    while true:
        prints("Insert some text:")
        var line := OS.read_string_from_stdin().strip_edges()
        prints("You inserted:", line)
        match line:
            "quit":
                prints("Quitting")
                _input_thread.wait_to_finish.call_deferred()
                quit.call_deferred()
                return
```

By the way, you know that we usually use `get_tree().quit()`, well, we are running the code on the `SceneTree`, so we just need to call `quit`. But we do not want to call it from our secondary `Thread`. A deferred call solves that.

Similarly, we are having the main thread wait for our secondary `Thread` to finish, so we do not leak the `Thread`.

However, this is not perfect, I have run into a couple problems:

- In PowerShell I only get one character at a time. The naive workaround made it unusable.
- In CMD the console gets the input first. So I need to press Enter which has CMD reply with the prompt, and then what I type gets send into the game.

So, don't. Instead create a bat file, like this:

```
my_game.exe --headless
```

And use that to launch the game server instead of CMD or PowerShell.

---

### Your Error

This seems to be a regresion of these bug:

- [Several errors are being printed in Godot external console when its window is closed with X](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/81056)
- [Loads of errors when i quit my app but no one indicates where in the script](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/84410)

This might be related:

- [Arbitrary crashes (seemingly) due to Point2i method [Linux]](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/82864)

If you can make a minimum reproduction project, please report at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

---

### Exit Notifications

> is there a notification I can use to save game state?

*I suppose you are aware of `NOTIFICATION_WM_CLOSE_REQUEST`, but these are Window Messages, so they won't work on headless mode.*

---

Your `Node`s will be removed from the scene tree. So their `_exit_tree` gets called, and they also get a `NOTIFICATION_EXIT_TREE` right away, followed by `NOTIFICATION_UNPARENTED` a little later.

If your cleanup needs to happen from an `Node` while inside the scene tree use `_exit_tree` or `NOTIFICATION_EXIT_TREE` in one of your Autoloads.

---

Futhermore, *many* `Object`s will get a `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE`. Use this as your finalizer.

*And those `Object`s also get a final undocumented notification `3` which internally has the name `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE_CLEANUP`... Which is not intended for you to use.*

---

But your static variables are not attached to an `Object`, let alone to a `Node`. Let us say you must clean them manually when you know the executable is losing.

Well, let us go back to our custom `MainLoop`, and override the `_finalize` method:

```
func _finalize() -> void:
    prints("_finalize")
```

After everything else is said and done, your `_finalize` will be called. And yes, you can access your `static var`s in `_finalize`. As far as I know it is your last chance.

*Oh, but we would have an instance `CustomMainLoop`, does it also get notifications? Yes. Does it get `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE` or `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE_CLEANUP`? No, it does not.*

---

**Addendum**: The [`@static_unload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_%40gdscript.html#class-gdscript-annotation-static-unload) has come to my attention. You should be able to annotate a script with it, for example:

```
@static_unload()
class_name MyClassWithStaticMembers

static var _something:Resource
```

And this would tell Godot that it can free the static variables early.

---

### Leaked Objects

Ah, but let me tell you something: your `Script`s are `Object`s, and they do not get to be freed in the above process. Also you might have `preload` some `Resource`s that would not have been freed yet - unless you freed them manually (and I'm not suggesting you do that). And there might be other Godot internal `Object`s lingering around.

If you run your executable with `--verbose` you will get everything that is being leaked printed after `_finalize` is called. Of course they get freed when the executable exits nontheless.

These do not cause the error you are seeing. The error you are seeing is caused by a bug. If you can make a minimum reproduction project, please report at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: This seems to work and solves my problems. I'm now getting a different error that is already reported [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/86806)