# How do i get key input using c#

Tags: c#, input, godot

To change key configuration i need to get the key input but after looking around i havent found any way of doing that using c#.The other way is using the Gd programming language.but i cant do that as my whole script(works) is using c# including the object that has the key detection script so changing the language will couse me a lot of problem:(

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to get which key is configured, their state, or how to change them. Si I kind of answered everything, hoping I covered what you want.  By the way, I'll also point out that despite the fact that you are using C#, you can still use GDScript in your project (I mean you can use both C# and GDScript in the same project).

Comment: this is useful for my project but i wanted to know how to get a key similiar to using console.readkey

Comment: As in standard input, like I did for this answwer: [What is the correct way to stop a Godot dedicated server](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/209066/10408) (except that is not C#)?

Comment: i made a thread,connected it to my getkey function,called the readstringfromstdn method and got nothing.I think this might be a problem with it not having enough time to get an input but i am not sure as i have never used it before.

Comment: I think it only works on headless mode.

Comment: oh okay,can you check out please my new answer below,i was able to get the input but i have a problem where i need to go outside my window to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for getting the key input:

```cs
      public override void _Input(InputEvent @event)
  {
      base._Input(@event);
      if (@event is InputEventKey inputKey && isRemapping==true)
      {
          Key c = inputKey.Keycode;
          GD.Print(c);
          Pressed = inputKey;
          GetViewport().SetInputAsHandled();
          isRemapping = false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Please try what I added to my answer. I can't test C# right now.

Answer (score 0):

---

### Awaiting a key

I believe we can create a custom signal for this:

```
[Signal]
public delegate void KeyPressedEventHandler();

public override void _Input(InputEvent @event)
{
    base._Input(@event);
    if (@event is InputEventKey inputKey)
    {
          EmitSignal(SignalName.KeyPressed);
    }
}
```

And then we should be able to await it:

```
await ToSignal(this, SignalName.KeyPressed);
```

---

### General Input

Although I believe you already know how to check if an action is pressed, let us look at it again. You can, for example, do this:

```
Input.IsActionPressed("Move_Up")
```

Or this for analog input:

```
Input.GetActionStrength("Move_Up")
```

Now that `String` must match an action configured in project settings. So we are talking about reading and writing project settings.

However, input is handled a bit different than the rest. There are a couple things to know:

- The `InputMap` gives you access to the input settings. So we will be using that.
- What is getting stored in project settings are `InputEvent`s. Yes, the class of objects you get in `_Input`. They are `Resource`s, so they can be saved. And what Godot is doing is matching the input it gets to the stored ones.

---

Before we go on, I need to point out that manipulating `InputMap` on the editor (i.e. `tool` scripts) will give you access to the editor settings instead. And yes, you can end up messing them up.

---

First, to find out if a action is configured we can do this:

```
if (InputMap.has_action("Action_Name"))
{
    GD.Print("The action exists");
}
```

Second, if you want to find the names of all the actions that are configured do:

```
foreach (var action_name in InputMap.GetActions())
{
    GD.Print(action_name);
}
```

Third, to get the `InputEvent`s associated with an action, you do this:

```
foreach (var @event in InputMap.ActionGetEvents("My_ActioN"))
{
    GD.Print(@event);
}
```

Fourth, this is what I do to change them:

```
InputMap.ActionEraseEvents("My_Action");
foreach (var new_event in my_events)
{
    InputMap.ActionAddEvent("My_Action", new_event);
}
```

And I remind you that those events are `InputEvent`, so you can get them from `_Input` and add them to `InputMap`. *You probably want to filter them to the device the player is using (e.g. which controller). And remember leaving a way to cancel or restore the original settings.*

---

You, of course, will also want to be able to save these, and for that I remind you that they are `Resource`s. So you can use `ResourceSaver` and `ResourceLoader`.

However, if you rather not...

- For keyboard: From `InputEventKey` you can use either `keycode` or `physical_keycode`. And you might also want to store `alt_pressed`, `ctrl_pressed`, `shift_pressed` and `meta_pressed`.
- For mouse:

  - From `InputEventMouseButton` you use `button_index`.
  - From `InputEventMouseMotion`... I don't have code for this per-se. Instead I have sensitivity and invert axis.
- For joystick:

  - From `InputEventJoypadButton` you use `button_index`.
  - From `InputEventJoypadMotion` you use `axis` and `axis_value` (probably just the sign).

  **Addendumm**: In both cases you identify the device by the `device` property.

**Note**: I'm looking on my GDScript code for the property names. I presume the capitalization is different on C#.

---

**Bonus**: if you want to mimic input, there is `Input.ActionPress` and `Input.ActionRelease`. There is also `Input.ParseInputEvent` which requires an `InputEvent`. There have been some bugs around these in Godot 4+ (either not doing anything or input getting stuck), so test if `ParseInputEvent` works better than `ActionPress` and `ActionRelease` on your version.